# How to disable Windows-S shortcut in Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-8.1

I had some program responding on <kbd>Windows</kbd> -<kbd>S</kbd> keystroke in `Windows 8`. But currently, in `Windows 8.1` "**Search everywhere**" window appears.

How to disable this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solve this by editing the Registry 
copy the code below in a Notepad and save it as `whatever.reg` (you rename the `.txt` to `.reg`)
This is actually a better solution because you do not need to disable all WinKeys.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
"DisabledHotkeys"="S"
```

Then run the file and answer yes to all windows.
That's it!

Or do it manually by opening the registry going to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`
then create a new string value key, name it `DisabledHotkeys`, right click on it, Modify, add `S` in value Data.

PS If you would like to disable more windows keys, say Win+C for example, in value data write S,C

Comment: Very nice. Works much better than gpedit.

Comment: Logout is required also. 10x

Answer (score 3):

You can either use [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) or windows [group policy](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3541.html) to disable key board shortcut.

> 1) Open Start menu and type gpedit.msc in the search box and press Enter key
>   2) In the Local Group Policy Editor window click to expand the folder
>
> User Configuration\Administrative Templates\ Windows Components\File Explorer given in the left pane
>
> 3) Now double click on Turn off Windows + X hotkeys option in the right pane
>
> 4) In the Turn off Windows + X hotkeys Properties window click the dot Not Configured or Disabled to enable Key Shortcuts
>
> OR
>
> Click the dot Enabled to disable Key Shortcuts
>
> 5) Click Apply and then OK button
>
> 6) Close the Local Group Policy Editor window.
>
> 7) Now Log off and Log on or Restart your PC

Comment: Is it possible to disable only `Windows-S` shortcut, not all `Windows-*` shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

For the following keys, Win+X combinations can't be disabled with the solution from Entropy (and probably at all): `- = U I P H K X C < >`

Example reg import file:

> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced]
> "DisabledHotkeys"="1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,q,w,t,s,d,f,b"

Explorer restart is enough to apply the changes.