# Changing or disabling Windows Search (Win + S) shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, search, shortcuts, screenshot, snipping-tool

Is there any way to change this shortcut? I use Crop Screenshot (<kbd>Win</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>) quite often, but sometimes I do it pretty fast and it interferes with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, which brings up the search bar. There is an option to bring the Crop Screenshot with the Print Screen button, but it's a bit tricky to use (Laptop Keyboard).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disable Windows-S shortcut in Windows 8.1](https://superuser.com/questions/683274/how-to-disable-windows-s-shortcut-in-windows-8-1)

Comment: This disables 'S' key from all shortcuts. The Cropped Screenshot also uses S.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To intercept and nullify a key can be done using a third-party product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You would use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
#S::return
```

You may further intercept the key only on condition that the snipping tool
is running by using the
[Process, Exist](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Process.htm#Exist)
command.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)